# Best way to encrypt string of digits

Tags: algorithm, encryption, digits

So we have a string of digits, lets say:

1234567890

we would like to encrypt this with a number.
the encrypted string is supposed capturable, and should be obfusciated

Lets say this string has one digit, lets say the 1 (one) which changes to for example 2.

After encryption the string has to be obfusciated, and not just changing the first digit from 2 tot 8 or something

So we are doing some research and are looking at 3DES

we take the approach of k1=k3 and k2

so

k1 = 1111111111
k2 = 2222222222
k3 = k1
encryptedString = encryptk1(decryptk2(encryptk3(message)))

so k2 is our public key, and k1 and k3 are the private keys.

Now we are looking for an algoritm that encrypts the message the right way:

at this time we made it simple for us, so we did:

(message[0] + k1[0]).substr(length-1,1)

So we take the last digit of the result. But this is working as folows.

When the message[0] changes, the encryptedmessage[0] changes, but the rest of the string isnt so obviously this isnt a workable approach.

So im asking to you, what ways are thinkable about encrypting this string the right way? It should be a simple algorithm since it has to be run on embedded hardware.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Do you want to have ability to decrypt it back?

Comment: yup, it should be decrypted back again. Since it's a string of numbers, it's not easy to brute-force back since you don't know when a string of numbers is the right one so you can't recognize the right privatekey. So that's why I suppose the algo shouldn't have to be really difficult.

Comment: Why don't you simply use a certified crypto like Rijndael instead of reinventing the wheel?

Comment: I'll take a look at that, I'm not a cryptographer so I did not hear about that yet. Thanks for the advise

Comment: Are you asking how to encrypt data? Or to encrypt with a public/private key pair? Or to encrypt a string of digits with a key, resulting in a new string of digits, a.k.a. format-preserving encryption.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `RSA` algorithm which widely used by industry in many areas from digital signatures to network communication.

[Here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0490__Security/BasicRSAexample.htm) is simple usage in java.

Also as sad [Dan Boneh](https://www.coursera.org/instructor/~85) don't try invent your own crypto algorithm if you does not have appropriate backroung. it's better to use widely known algorithms.